# Why I see several completed jobs in task manager when I run just one job in Apache Flink?

Tags: apache-flink

In Apache Flink, I run a task on a remote cluster. I have a task containing the following command.
I was wondering, why Flink web client consider my task as several different job in the completed jobs?

```
personRecords =    env.readCsvFile("path to input file/dataset1.csv")
                .lineDelimiter("\n").ignoreFirstLine()
                .fieldDelimiter(",")           
                .includeFields("111")
                .types(Integer.class, String.class, String.class);

pData = personRecords.map(new cleanerMap());
pData = pData.sortPartition(3, Order.ASCENDING).setParallelism(1);
env.setParallelism(4);
MultiKey_List = partitionedData.collect();
...
pData = p.partitionCustom(new MyPartitioner(), 3);
DataSet<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>> dPairs =    pData.mapPartition(new  Calc());
dPairs = dPairs.flatMap(new TC(dPairs.collect())).setParallelism(1);
env.execute();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because the `collect` command triggers the execution of the job up to the point where you call it. Thus, it is unlike almost all other api calls eagerly evaluated. The other method which triggers the execution of the job is `count`.

All other sinks which you define after the `collect` will be executed by a subsequent `collect` call or when you call `ExecutionEnvironment.execute`.

Comment: So do you mean in this case,  I would have 3 jobs, as I have 2 collect commands and 1 execute command?

Comment: Yes, in this case you should see three jobs.